# How to replace elements of a matrix in C++ with values from another matrix (using Rcpp)?

Tags: c++, r, matrix, rcpp

I have a small C++ function using Rcpp that replaces elements of one matrix with values from another matrix.  It works fine for single cells, or a column as below:

```
cppFunction('NumericMatrix changeC(NumericMatrix one, NumericMatrix two) {
NumericMatrix a = one;
NumericMatrix b = two;
b(_,1) = a(_,1);
return b;
}')

changeC(g,f)
```

If originally f is the following matrix:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    6    6    6    6    6    6
[2,]    6    6    6    6    6    6
[3,]    6    6    6    6    6    6
[4,]    6    6    6    6    6    6
[5,]    6    6    6    6    6    6
[6,]    6    6    6    6    6    6
```

and g looks like the following matrix:

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    5    5    5    5    5    5
 [2,]    5    5    5    5    5    5
 [3,]    5    5    5    5    5    5
 [4,]    5    5    5    5    5    5
 [5,]    5    5    5    5    5    5
 [6,]    5    5    5    5    5    5
```

When I run changeC(g,f) I end up with (as expected):

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    6    5    6    6    6    6
[2,]    6    5    6    6    6    6
[3,]    6    5    6    6    6    6
[4,]    6    5    6    6    6    6
[5,]    6    5    6    6    6    6
[6,]    6    5    6    6    6    6
```

But what I really want to do is replace a subset of one matrix with a subset of another matrix from a different place (eg rows 1 to 3, columns 1 to 3 of one matrix (3*3) to rows 3 to 6, columns 3 to 6 (also 3*3) of the other matrix). I have tried:

```
cppFunction('NumericMatrix changeC(NumericMatrix one, NumericMatrix two) {
NumericMatrix a = one;
NumericMatrix b = two;
b( Range(0,2), Range(0,2)) = a( Range(3,5), Range(3,5));
return b;
}')
```

but this doesn't compile.  Although:

```
cppFunction('NumericMatrix changeC(NumericMatrix one, NumericMatrix two) {
NumericMatrix a = one;
NumericMatrix b = two;
b = a( Range(3,5), Range(3,5));
return b;
}')
```

does compile.  What am I doing wrong? In R I would do the following:

f[1:3,1:3] <- g[4:6,4:6] (but this is relatively slow with a very large matrix (hence Rcpp).

Thanks for any help in advance.

**EDIT 1**

After a bit of playing around I've managed to get my matrix to step east and west (and I assume it would be similar to north and south - possibly a two step approach for North East, North West??):

```
func <- 'NumericMatrix eastC(NumericMatrix a) {
int acoln=a.ncol();
NumericMatrix out(a.nrow(),a.ncol()) ;
for (int j = 0;j < acoln;j++) {
if (j > 0) {
out(_,j) = a(_,j-1);
 } else {
  out(_,j) = a(_,0);
 }
 }
 return out ;
 }'
 cppFunction(func)
```

Any refinements would be welcome.  I would ideally like to leave the first column as zeros rather than column 0.  Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you do this with a couple of nested for-loops?

Comment: Can you demonstrate please - I'm very new to C++?

Comment: In moving from R to C++, you have to do a lot of the steps that R would do natively. IE- R is vectorized, C++ is not. As 42 notes, doing this via two loops (rows, columns) is one option. Another option would be to use [block operations](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html) in RcppEigen

Comment: Also, you should pass-by-reference and use `const` on the matrix that doesn't change (`one` in your first example)

Comment: Alex, 42, I definitely want to explore what you are saying but not sure how to do it.  Would you post an answer please?

Comment: I may have some time to do so this afternoon

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think the Rcpp subMatrix allows for assignments that way.

Take a look at using RcppArmadillo and [Armadillo submatrix views](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat)

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat example( mat m1, mat m2) {
  m1.submat( 0,0, 2,2) = m2.submat( 3,3, 5,5 );
  return m1;
}

/*** R
m1 <- matrix(1,6,6)
m2 <- matrix(-1,6,6)
example(m1, m2)
*/
```

---

```
> m1 <- matrix(1,6,6)

> m2 <- matrix(-1,6,6)

> example(m1, m2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   -1   -1   -1    1    1    1
[2,]   -1   -1   -1    1    1    1
[3,]   -1   -1   -1    1    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
[5,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
[6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

Comment: I would like to try RcppArmadillo - but where do you write this code?  in R? or in another editor and compile it?  All I get is errors when I try and write this in R - as you can tell I have no experience of using Armadillo.  My C++ code above was written and compiled within R.

Comment: Create a `test.cpp` file, and use 'sourceCpp("test.cpp")` which is part of your Rcpp package. Also, read the Rcpp vignettes. :)

Comment: I have - in vain.  Thanks for the pointer - tried it - got it now. Super thanks - I've been struggling all day on how to read in this type of code.

Comment: There is definitely potential in using Armadillo now I can use it - I don't think it will be much quicker than my above code but definitely more control.

Comment: I should be quicker, and as Alex said in the comments; use pass by reference (and don't forget const).

Comment: In the end I used the nested for loops to move the matrix one step left or right (to simulate E or W) - this is very quick - and the Armadillo subset.matrix to move a matrix one row up or down (to simulate S or N) - slower but quicker than the for loop method by some margin. A mixture of the two for SE, NW etc. Really pleased. Thanks.